# Is there any good way to get a smaller C#-XmlSerialized file?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, size, xmlserializer

I use C# xmlSerializer to serialize/deserialize a big object contains many members. And the saved file is very large, like 8~10M. Is there any good way to get a small file? like 500k?

my code like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class WellInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{       
    public Int32 WellIndex { get; set; }   
    public string WellName { get; set; }
    private WellType _eWellType;     
    public WellType eWellType
    {
        get
        {
            return _eWellType;
            }
            set
            {                
                 _eWellType = value;
            }
        }
    
        private string _strWellType;
        /// <summary>
        /// well type
        /// </summary>
        public string strWellType
        {
            get
            {
                return _strWellType;
            }
            set
            {
                _strWellType = value;
                InvokePropertyChanged("strWellType");
            }
        }
        .........
        //many object members 
        .........
}

 public static int SaveAsConfig(WellInfo info, string FullPath)
        {
          if (info== null)  return -1;   

           using (var fs = new FileStream(FullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
           {
              using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fs, des.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
               {
                  XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WellInfo));
                            xs.Serialize(cryptoStream, info);
               }                   
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

How to serialize or deserialize object from a file simply and get a small-size file like 500k?

Comment: You could write the data to a [GZipStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=net-7.0).

Comment: You can get a somewhat smaller XML by using attributes instead of elements for values (`[XmlAttribute]`), maybe with shorter names (like `[XmlAttribute("A")]`) and if many values are identical by using `[DefaultValue("VeryCommonValue")]`, but this will never get you a factor of 10.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, can you explain why you want to reduce the size of the output file? If they have to use **xml**, to reduce its size, either you have to divide the output file into several parts of 500k and output it, or reduce the file size with different algorithms, some of which are in the **.Net Framwork** itself, such as **GZipStream** .

**Second**, in structures such as **XML**, compared to **JSON**, the size of the output file is much larger due to the presence of various tags. Therefore, JSON files were much lighter due to the absence of tags and additional file elements, and it is also faster to save and load, that's why if you don't have a special compulsion to use xml, you can use **JSON**.

Comment: About this application, the user will save many files in one day. So the files should not occupy too much space. And the file should not be divided to several parts.  I don't have to use xml. If there are other good methods, I could change the serialize style. Thanks. I'll try JSON format.